# Django cache get expired entry

Tags: django, caching, get

In my views, I have the following

```
@require_POST
def loadVals(request):
  result = //do some heavy calculations
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": result}), content_type="application/json")
```

Now I have added a cache so that I do not have to perform "heavy calclations" all the time. So the new code looks like

settings.py

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake'
}
```

}

views.py

```
from django.core.cache import get_cache

@require_POST
def loadVals(request):
  cache = get_cache('default')
  result = cache.get('res')
  if result == NONE:
    result = //do some heavy calculations
    cache.set('res', result, 30)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": result}), content_type="application/json")
  else:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": result}), content_type="application/json")
```

What I want to do instead is that even if that cache has expired, I want to save the front end user some wait time(because of heavy calculations) and just return the last expired value.
And then refresh the cache.

How do I

1) get the value of expired cache? because cache.get('res') return NONE if cache has expired

2) make a call after the return HttpResponse statement to refresh the cache value and do heavy calculations( where return statmenet just returned the expired value) OR may be do this via asynchronous calls?

Answer (score 2):

First, your code has some syntax problems. 
Second, you cannot get an expired value from django cache. Expired values are removed once they expire, after they just don't exist anymore.

If you want to store expired values longer for this kind of case you need to store they in a more persistent storage like a database, cache is not made for that.

Or you can cache your result two times one of which is longer and serve from the second cache:

```
from django.core.cache import get_cache

@require_POST
def loadVals(request):
    cache = get_cache('default')
    result = cache.get('res') or cache.get('res_long')
    if result is None:
        result = //do some heavy calculations
        cache.set('res', result, 30)
        cache.set('res_long', result, 60*60*24*7) # cache for a week
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": result}), content_type="application/json")
```

This is still not a great approach because you still have to do something to re-cache the short cache. Also it's not great because you overload your cache backend with double data.

If you want your users to always get cached content, try to cache it with background tasks using [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/index.html) for example.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me:

1) create a global variable, and when you set the cache, set this global variable too. if the cache has expired, your global variable is still around with expired values, so send that in response. and use threading to update the cache and global variable.

2) use python threading

```
import  threading
def loadVals():
    threading.Thread(group=None, target=methodToDoheavyCalculations).start()
    # return the expired cache in the meanwhile
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(EXPIRED_VALUES), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Nice use of threading. Unfortunately, there is no guarantee from wsgi that the process is going to be around for the next request. So using threading for persistent cache is an anti-pattern.